# Primefaces push with GlassFish 4.0

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, atmosphere, glassfish-4

Has anyone succeed in using above configuration? I am trying to use push with growl from primefaces. I am using primefaces 3.5 GlassFish 4.0 and Atmosphere 2.0.0.RC5  My config is as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The Bean method:

```
private void assaginTreatment()
  {
    ...
    PushContext pushContext = PushContextFactory.getDefault().getPushContext();
    pushContext.push("/notifications", facesMsg);
    return;
  }
```

And finally the xhtml file:

```
 <p:growl widgetVar="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" globalOnly="true" autoUpdate="true" />
            <p:socket onMessage="handleMessage" channel="/notifications" autoConnect="true"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function handleMessage(facesmessage) {
                    facesmessage.severity = 'info';
                    PF('growl').show([facesmessage]);
                }
            </script>
```

The error I am getting is:

`SEVERE:   [http-listener-1(4)] WARN org.atmosphere.cpr.MetaBroadcaster - No Broadcaster match /notifications. Message...`

Comment: I get the same problem (and error log) for GF4.0 Primefaces4.0.RC1 and atmosphere-2.0.0.RC5, same app worked with primefaces 3.5, atmosphere 1.0.17 and gf3.1.2.2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atmosphere-2.0.0.RC5, Primefaces-4.0.RC1

I managed to do a workaround which isnt nice really, but pushing to all, made it work. Might be enough for your usecase

```
pushContext.push("/*", facesMsg);
```

Edit:
So i did some further debuging and added some more logging

```
if (BroadcasterFactory.getDefault() != null) {
    Collection<Broadcaster> list = BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookupAll();
    for (Broadcaster b : list) {
        logger.warn("id={}", b.getID() );
    }
}
```

output:

```
Info: 2013-09-17 22:43:10,010 - id=/*
Info: 2013-09-17 22:43:10,010 - id=/notificationsprimepush
```

so finally i tried:

```
pushContext.push("/notifications" + "primepush", facesMsg);
```

WORKED! :)

Comment: Very good, thanks for sharing here and to PrimeFaces Push forum/community.

Comment: One more thing did you also resolve the ` WARN org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework - No BroadcasterCache configured. Broadcasted message between client reconnection will be LOST. It is recommended to configure the org.atmosphere.cache`